# Обработка ошибок в Redux Saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Стандартно обрабатываю ошибку как на скрине. Если произошла ошибка, текст ошибки приходит в resonse. Проблема в том, что я не знаю как его оттуда вытащить. Запрос прервался, response остался пустым. Есть способы сделать запрос так, чтобы response  пришел, даже в случае ошибки. И как это сделать в саге?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Напишите функцию-"обёртку" над методами axios, например для GET-запроса это будет выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
const serviceGet = ({ url, params }) => {
  const config = {
    params,
    // пропускаем все статусы больше или = 200
    validateStatus: status => status >= 200, 
  };
  return axios
    .get(url, { params })
    .then((response) => {
      // статусы с серверными ошибками прокидываем с серверными данными
      // чтобы сработал catch блок в сагах
      if (response.status >= 400) {
        throw response.data && response.data.error;
      }

      return response;
    })
};
```

В саге:

```
const response = yield call(serviceGet, ({ url, params }));
```

Дело в том, что axios по-умолчанию реджектит статусы:

```
status >= 200 && status < 300
```

и вам необходимо эту логику немного расширить, чтобы читать ответ сервера, а не ошибку, сгенерированную axios.